# Check constraint noninfringement in PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have just created a model in PuLP, though its result seems to have violated its constraints. Is there a quick way to check the value of each constraint?

Comment: `Is there a quick way to check the value of each constraint?` That would require a solution / assignment or else there is no value. I don't think there is some helpful machinery available in pulp. You would need some concept first. Usually, you can say that cons A + D won't work together. But you could also return B + C + D won't work together. There is some formal concept needed about what to ask. Commercial solvers (only when used with their native APIs i guess) have support for infeasibility analysis. But that's probably not interfaced in pulp and open-source solvers miss this feature too

Comment: Some people do the following: A) Adapt your implementation to easy deactivate constraints and do various runs with some of those subsets (start with size-1 first) deactivated. B) More technical: Introduce a boolean-var for each constraint and deactivate it depending on this boolean-var. Optimize the sum of those vars to infer how many of your constraints can work together at best. But this involves some big-M formulations and might be not much fun.

Comment: what is the solver status in the output?